# XHR same origin errors in AngularJS AJAX to NodeJS server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ajax

I'm running an app in AngularJS locally that usually points to an REST API in NodeJS. Everything's working fine in production, where front-end and api are served in different domains.

The issue is running these locally. I can start the front-end on `localhost:3000` and keep it pointed to the remote api, but when i try to point it to the api locally in `localhost:9000`, i get the following:

`DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL`

I'm using browserSync to start the front-end on port 3000, and pm2 to start the server on port 9000. The API's running fine via browser and postman.

Comment: Did you write `http://` before `localhost:9000`?

Comment: Yes. I solved it putting `/` after `localhost:9000`. Thanks!